# Use Appium to make a telephone call on Android device

Tags: android, appium, phone-call

I would appreciate some help with some test automation on Android devices. We use Appium and RemoteWebDriver code to access the Android emulator, open up our application, tap and move around the application UI, and this all seems to work well.

However, as part of my testing, I would like to use Appium to initiate a telephone call on the device, keep the call open for a minute or so, and then hang up. Is there away to do this through the RemoteWebDriver object?

If not, what is the recommended way to make calls on the emulator? I have seen some discussion of using direct telnet calls to the emulator, but hope there is a better way!

Answer (score 2):

**You may set these desired capabilities :**

```
      capabilities.setCapability("androidPackage", "com.android.dialer");
      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "DialtactsActivity");
```

**and use this snippet to make call via Appium :**

```
remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("com.android.dialer:id/search_view")).sendKeys("NAME_OF_PERSON");        
remoteWebDriver.findElements(By.id("com.android.dialer:id/dialer_search_item_view")).get(0).click();
```

This would make call to the first search item

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(60000); //
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("com.android.dialer:id/endButton")).click();
```

This would disconnect the call after 60 seconds.

Comment: I think op means to background his app, then make call, so I don't think it make sense to use capabilities to set package and activity. I think one can open another app without changing the caps of the test. And one is also able to background the app under test non blocking by just sending home button key event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a start a phone call using ADB:

```
public static int makePhoneCall(AppiumDriver driver, Srting deviceId, String phoneNum, int callDuration) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    callDuration *= 1000;
    cmd = "adb -s " + deviceId + " shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:" + phoneNum; //open a Dialer and placing a call right away
    Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); //starting a call and..
    Thread.sleep(callDuration);//..waiting for callDuration seconds before hangup
    driver.sendKeyEvent(6);// hang up phonecall
    return exec.exitValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is possible, though perhaps a little more painfully than I expected. I had to do two things: specify the correct app to open, and work out the xpath references to the buttons on the dial pad. The activity is com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity and the xpaths to some of the buttons are:

1. Number text field: /linear/linear/editText
2. Number 1 button: /linear/table/row[1]/imageButton[1]
3. Number 5 button: /linear/table/row[2]/imageButton[2]
4. Dial button: /linear/frame/imageButton

If anyone has a better way to do this, I'd be very pleased to see it! Martin

Answer (score 0):

1. press home button 
   driver.sendKeyEvent(3);
2. Press call button.
   dr.sendKeyEvent(5);
3. locate dial pad 
   driver.findElementById("com.android.dialer:id/dialpad_button").click();
4. type number by send key or by sendKeyEvents.
   driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys(phoneNumber);
5. Press call button
   driver.findElementById("com.android.dialer:id/dial_button").click();
6. put some wait and press End call button.
   dr.findElementById("com.android.dialer:id/endButton").click();